# Access Point Iptable/Route rule for allowing device discovery? Devices can connect manually, but not automatically. Multicast/Upnp issue?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, routing, wifi

I setup a wireless access point on my server and for some reason, everything works but automatic discovery features. I can't see any other devices, upnp devives aren't discovered, and I think it's a simple iptable or route issue I'm missing.

Example:

- Device A plugged in ethernet discovers 20 local devices
- Device A plugged in wireless discovers itself and the wifi only
- Device A plugged in wireless CAN connect to others if manually specified IP
- Device A can see NO other UpNp/DLNA/Share/Etc hooked wireless, but can ethernet

I solved this a long time ago, but can't remember what I did.

```
sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.189.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:31:1e:4b
          inet addr:192.168.100.153  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fb1:56b0:c113:f046/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:281701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:75550664 (72.0 MiB)  TX bytes:19734709 (18.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2491 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2491 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:234335 (228.8 KiB)  TX bytes:234335 (228.8 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:64:4b:1e
          inet addr:192.168.189.1  Bcast:192.168.189.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f855:75b1:b821:5f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26313 errors:0 dropped:24582 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4191579 (3.9 MiB)  TX bytes:966693 (944.0 KiB)
```

network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0 # managed by ifplugd
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#hwaddress ether 1a:64:b6:bf:36:37

#allow-hotplug wlan0
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#pre-up wpa_supplicant -B w -D wext -i wlan0 -c /opt/max2play/wpa_supplicant.co$
#post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant






#Accesspoint start
up iptables-restore < /etc/hostapd/iptables.ap
#Accesspoint end
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       UnitThree
192.168.189.1     UnitThree
```

**Edit** : formating

Answer (score 0):

You are probably routing the answers to the wrong interface.

```
ip route add 239.255.255.250 dev wlan0
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Full Multicast routing gets much trickier (so much easier in the days of hubs).  There is a package to install to make it much easier.
2. WiFi is configured to not allow a WiFi device to talk to another WiFi device.